# @CreationTimestamp change date format

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I use Spring Boot, PostreSQL, JPA
Have some @Entity with created_at column in database

```
@CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDate createdAt;
```

This is above results in 2020-08-31 in database, but I need 31.08.2020. How i can change it ?

I tried:

1. application.properties spring.jackson.date-format=dd.MM.YYYY
2. 

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.YYYY")
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDate createdAt;
```

3. Tried change LocalDate to Date

Comment: Format it when you _display_ the value

Comment: You do understand that the format you're 'seeing' in the DB is just a reflection of how the DB introspection tool you're using decides to display the value, right? It's not like the DB stores the `TIMESTAMP` as an actual formatted string...

Comment: @crizzis thank you. Now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have an LocalDate object but you need a representation of your date (like in a String). You can get such a representation with a formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd");
String formattedLocalDate = createdAt.format(formatter);
```